# How do I iterate through a string.Split() array, joining LINQ query results for each item together?

Tags: vb.net, linq

In my application, I have a search query textbox (txtSearch) that works well with one-word queries with the following LINQ:

```
slstFilteredItems = From s In slstItems _
                    Where s.strText.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 _
                    Select s
```

But if you search this with a multiple-word query, say "Create customer" (no quotes), it only finds results that contain the result "Create Customer" exactly (case-insensitive).

So the simplest way to handle this that I can think of is with a query that does a .Intersect with each word in sequence, like this:

```
slstFilteredItems = (From s In slstItems _
                    Where s.strText.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text.Split(" ")(0), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 _
                    Select s).Intersect _
                    (From s In slstItems _
                    Where s.strText.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text.Split(" ")(1), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 _
                    Select s)
                    'And so on...
```

So how would I make the above query more generic (ie: able to handle any number of words in a query)?

I should note that the object being queried is a List of strings pulled from an Access database.  As it stands, this application only queries the database once and I'd like to keep it that way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for an arbitrary number of items in the txtSearch.text.Split array

```
slstFilteredItems = (From splits In txtSearch.Text.Split(" ").ToList _
                    From s In slstItems _
                    Where s.strText.IndexOf(splits, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 _
                    Select s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach:

```
Dim words = "Dog cAt biRD"
Dim slstItems = New String() { "dog thing cat bird ", "bird cat", "cat foo dog bird " }

'Query Syntax (with some fluent syntax)
Dim q = From s In slstItems.Select(Function(x) x.ToLower())
        Where words.Split(" ").Select(Function(x) x.ToLower()).All(Function(x) s.Contains(x))
        Select s

'All Fluent Syntax 
slstItems.Select(Function(x) x.ToLower()) _
    .Where(Function(s) words.Split(" ").Select(Function(x) x.ToLower()) _
                        .All(Function(w) s.Contains(w)) _
    )
```

Both return:

```
dog thing cat bird   
cat foo dog bird
```

Note that this is inefficient when compared to bigtlb's answer (which is a much better solution for database searching).

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting a SQL Server Database, Full Text Searching may be a better approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  This is a list of strings pulled from an Access database that I'm filtering on the basis of the query.  I'll edit the question.